# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have an application developed in SugarCRM CE 6x. I have developed several module. Since yesterday one of application module is not working. Rest all modules are working fine but when I open the particular module (The module name is candidate by the way) it shows:

> "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxx\include\database\MysqliManager.php on line 132".

I am not able to figure it out how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

These Solutions may help you:
**1.** Looks like PHP may be timing out.
 Just double the memory_limit in php.ini and reboot your web service.

**2.** Try this , Navigate to the php.ini file and increase the default value of max_execution_time to 6000 seconds.